# Post request data to json in node

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, http-post

I am sending a simple ajax-jQuery post request:

```
$('#postButton').click (function () {
        var empInfo = $('#empForm').serialize();
        var empData = JSON.stringify(empInfo,null,2);

    $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'JSON',
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/post',
          data: empData, // check how to stringfy to json and send() .
          success: function(serverData){
              $('.thankU').html(serverData);
          }
        });
```

I have tried every way I know to get the data into json format on the node server:

```
app.post('/post', function(req, res){

    // get query params as object
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log("Received body data:");
        console.log(chunk.toString());
        console.log(JSON.parse(chunk) );
        console.log(qs.parse(chunk) );
        console.log(JSON.stringify(chunk));
    });
});
```

and the result is:

```
Received body data:
"bname=jjj&burl=jfjfj.com&bEmail=ff&bPhone=0608584884&fieldSelected=webPro"
bname=jjj&burl=jfjfj.com&bEmail=ff&bPhone=0608584884&fieldSelected=webPro
```

instead of the way it appears in developer tools\network :

```
"bname:jjj
burl:jfjfj.com
bEmail:ff
bPhone:0608584884
fieldSelected:webPro"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the jquery `serialize method` creates an encoded string out of the form: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

to get a json object, try to use `serializeArray` http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ instead. 
Or create your json object manually and read each form elements' `$().val()` value...

Your other code looks fine, you have to stringify the object and post it to the server.

Comment: i used the serialize method on other form that have the same selections and it worked fine , the only difference was the request type (get) instead of the post i'm trying now.

Comment: and as u can see in developer tools\network it send it in the json format .

Comment: well if you post, jquery will put the `data` into the post body and with serialize this will just be an encoded string and not a json object...
"bname=jjj&burl=jfjfj.com&bEmail=ff&bPhone=0608584884&fieldSelected=webPro" is not json. "{bname:jjj, burl:jfjfjcom...}" would be json

Comment: i use : var empInfo = $('#empForm').serialize();
  var empData = JSON.stringify(empInfo,null,2);              befor i send the ajax . i didnt say im 100% sure that the problem is on node .

Comment: `empInfo` is already a string. JSON.stringify just does nothing at that point, it just stringifies a string ^^

Comment: so what do u think i should do ?

Comment: try using serializeArray and see what you receive on the server

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
dataType: 'JSON',
```

to:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Comment: the dataType in other requests is 'JSON' as well , thats not the problem .